# How to call function every 2 mins in angular2?

Tags: angular, ionic2

How do I call a save function every two minutes in Angular2?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

**rxjs 6**

```
  import { interval } from 'rxjs';

  interval(2000 * 60).subscribe(x => {
    doSomething();
  });
```

**rxjs 5**

You can either use

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs'; // Angular 6 
// import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx'; // Angular 5

  Observable.interval(2000 * 60).subscribe(x => {
    doSomething();
  });
```

or just [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

**Hint:**

Angular >= 6.0.0 uses RxJS 6.0.0 [Angular Changelog 6.0.0](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#600-2018-05-03)

[RxJS v5.x to v6 Update Guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md)

Comment: The interval time isn't rather 12000 (1000ms * 60 * 2), @Günter? ;-)

Comment: If you use the .subscribe method, make sure to unsubscribe from it on ngOnDestroy. If you don't then your function will continue to run when the component is destroyed, e.g., navigating away from your component

Comment: I still don't understand anything you try to accomplish. Why would you do that? What do you mean with "realtime"? Get from where?

Comment: Can we use it to fetch data every 2 minute without any use interaction, mean, once user came and it will be working for ever without any use interaction?

Comment: It should be noted that importing from rxjs/Rx will import the entire rxjs library and increase the size of your deployment bundle. Consider importing only what you need. In this case: 
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';

Comment: Angular 6+, should be import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

Comment: @JuniorLeveDeveloper thanks for the hint - updated

Comment: from ng ^6.1 and rxjs ^6.2 you would have to use it like `interval(2000 * 60).subscribe(x => /* do something */)`

Comment: You can refer this,  https://stackoverflow.com/a/53082795/3763015

Comment: Property 'interval' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.

Comment: @69444091thanks for the hint. I updated my answer.