# How do I call a function in every 10 seconds in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

How do I call a function in a set Time interval in Angular 2. I want it to be called/Triggered at specific time intervals(for eg 10 secs).
For Eg:
ts File

```
num: number = 0;
array: number[] = [1,5,2,4,7];
callFuntionAtIntervals(){
    if(num==5){
        num=0;    
    }
    num++;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>{{ array[num] }}</div>
```

So basically the div value will change at intervals

Comment: Use `Observable.interval`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call function every 2 mins in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36133430/how-to-call-function-every-2-mins-in-angular2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 http at an interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35316583/angular2-http-at-an-interval)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Observable.interval(10000).takeWhile(() => true).subscribe(() => this.function());`

infinite loop where every each 10 seconds `function()` is being called

Comment: What does the `takeWhile` accomplish here?

Comment: takeWhile() subscribes and mirrors the source Observable until the condition is satisfied. In simple words to break out of the interval, it is used.

Comment: for eg :- 
You can initialize a boolean variable in class constructor as true, and then inside ngOnDestroy() you set that variable to false to come out of the interval. 
Hope this helps @user663031

Comment: error TS2339: Property 'interval' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.

Comment: Don't forget to unsubscribe it on `ngOnDestory()`

Answer (score 4):

You may also try the traditional setInterval function.

```
setInterval(() => {
    this.callFuntionAtIntervals();
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

In your TS logic, define an observable based on an "interval", which will emit the values 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, ...

```
this.index = Observable.interval(10000).map(n => n % this.array.length);
```

In your component, unwrap that observable using `async` and use it to index into the array.

```
{{array[index | async]}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check below it might be some helpful,

My requirements: Like every 5 secs need to call a service if we get back required data we need to stop calling the service and continue with next flow.  Else call service again after 5 seconds.

Conditions to stop service invocation were like after max number of retries (in my case 20 times) or after certain time (in my case 120 seconds).

Note: I was using in typescript

```
let maxTimeToRetry = 120000;  // in ms
let retryCount = 0;
let retryTimeout = 5000; // in ms
let maxRetries = 20;
const startTime = new Date().getTime();

// Need to use self inside of this, inside setInterval method;

const interval = setInterval(function () {
    retryCount++;  // INCREMENT RETRY COUNTER
    self.service.getData(requestParams).subscribe(result => {
      if (result.conditionTrue) {
        clearInterval(interval); // to stop the timer or to stop further calling of service
        //any execution after getting data
      }
    });

    if ((new Date().getTime() - startTime > maxTimeToRetry) || (retryCount === maxRetries)) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      // any execution 
    }

  }, retryTimeout);
```