# Use "new Function()" method in Angular 4/5 component.ts files

Tags: javascript, angular

Can anyone please guide that how can I use JavaScript's "new Function()" constructor method in Angular 4/5' component.ts files. It gives error while building.

```
my-tmpl.component.ts:108:14: Invalid character.
'ngc' errored after 4.08 s
[15:05:16] Error: ngc compilation failed
```

My Example code in *.component.ts:

```
public clickEvent() {
var myString = "setTimeout(function() {alert('Time Out fired')}, 100); alert('Hello'); return false;";

new Function(myString)(); }
```

Your help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Jignesh

Comment: This code is working in local Angular App as well as in Chrome Console.

Comment: Did you try using interval function instead to create new function? See the following [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36133464/6651984)