# Execute service function in background each 4 minutes in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, scheduled-tasks, angular-httpclient, background-service

I'm trying to execute a service function in the background that gets the refresh token from the server each 4 minutes.

```
 @Injectable()
 export class RefreshTokenService {
 time: any;
 token: string;
 email: string;
 credentials: any;

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
 }


  getToken(): string {
   const credentials = localStorage.getItem('credentials');
   if (credentials) {
     const parsedCredentials = JSON.parse(credentials);
     const token = parsedCredentials.token;
     return token;
   }
   return null;
  }

 refreshToken(token: string) {
   const tokenJson: any = {'token': token};
   this.http.post('/api-token-refresh/', tokenJson,   httpOptions).subscribe(response => {
     const data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
     this.credentials = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('credentials'));
     this.credentials.token = data.token;
     localStorage.setItem('credentials',  JSON.stringify(this.credentials));
   });
 }}
```

Now i'm executing the `refreshToken()` in `the app.component.ts` inside `ngOnInit()` , so it executes every time i load a page in the app, and it works as expected, but i haven't found a proper way to call the `refreshToken()` each 4 minutes in the background.

i already looked at this but it seem not to work... [How to call function every 2 mins in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36133430/how-to-call-function-every-2-mins-in-angular2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use `interval` and `switchMap` operator.

First, return an observable from the refreshToken function. Use map operator to do all other stuff like transforming data, storing in localstorage etc in `refreshToken()` method.

```js
import { interval, pipe } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

.....

refreshToken(token: string) {
   const tokenJson: any = {'token': token};
   return this.http.post('/api-token-refresh/', tokenJson,   httpOptions);
};

checkingTokenOnInterval(){
     const intervalTime = 4*60*1000;
     const token = 'sdfsdf';
     interval(intervalTime).pipe(switchMap(() => this.refreshToken(token))).subscribe(()=>{
                 //do something 
     });
}
```

Use `checkingTokenOnInterval()` for calling refreshToken call on every 4 minutes.

Comment: Should i call `checkingTokenOnInterval()` inside the `ngOnInit()` in the `app.component.ts` ?

Comment: yes if you want to call refreshToken on every 4 min

Comment: It does indeed execute after the period set in `intervalTime`,but it does execute only once and after that i gives this error `ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.`
have an idea how to fix it ?

Comment: I m not sure about this error, probably there will be some minor syntax error in rxjs code , but you can check this [stackblitz-demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-uqzdew?devtoolsheight=60)

Answer (score 1):

Be aware of requests that are sent right after refresh token request with old valid token. I recommend to use interceptor and queue all requests sent after refreshToken. Wait until refreshToken comes and then send queue requests.

Another way - catch 401 Error -> copy request -> refreshToken -> send copy of request.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using RxJS/timer https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/timer

```
    this.refreshTokenService.refreshToken()
        .pipe
            tap(() => {
                // every 4 minutes refresh the discovery service
                const interval = 4 * 60 * 1000;
                timer(interval, interval).subscribe(() => {
                    this.refresh().subscribe();
                });
            })
        )
        .toPromise();
```